# Architecture of Spring boot as backend and React as frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to make a project that uses spring boot as a backend and React as a frontend.
In the spring boot,

```
@GetMapping("/home")
```

I'll use that.

In React,

```
 axios({
            url: '/home',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then((res) => {
            callback(res.data);
        })
```

It was confirmed that the data was received by running it as 'npm start'.
However, there was a problem with using a docker.
When I returned using curl on Spring Boot, the result came out well.
React did not work properly. (Proxy setup is also completed.)
So Nginx and React were used together.
However, it did not work well.

Is it right to use Nginx when connecting Spring Boot and React?
I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me the architecture how to connect.
The architecture necessarily hopes for a spring boot of the back end and a react of the front using a docker.
However, if there is a better design, it is also good.
Perhaps, the proxy setting may be wrong? (Error does not appear and the value is blank.)

---

I added code.
Front/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm install —no-cache
RUN npm install -g react-scripts
RUN npm install -g react-router-dom
RUN apk add —no-cache git

COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {                     
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    upstream docker-nginx { 
        server client:3000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
     
        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://docker-nginx;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;          
        }
    }
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
                                                
    sendfile        on;                                                                         
    keepalive_timeout  65;                                                                      
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;           
}
```

front/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: web
    restart: "on-failure"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./web/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

      
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    container_name: client
    restart: "on-failure"
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - './client:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development 
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - clonet_network
    restart: always

networks:
  clonet_network:
    external: true
```

back/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  home:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Home/Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: ./Home/build/libs/*.jar
    container_name: home_con
    volumes:
      - ./Home:/app
    ports:
      - 2004:8080
    networks:
      - clonet_network
    restart: always

networks:
  clonet_network:
    external: true
```

---

I added this it in nginx.conf

```
location /home {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:2004;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;          
        }
```

localhost:80/home says '502 Bad Gateway'.

Comment: Build the react applicaiton and serve the static contents, dont have to proxy pass it. You can use react applicaiton as builder container and copy the files to nginx container https://tiangolo.medium.com/react-in-docker-with-nginx-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-including-testing-8cc49d6ec305 and proxy pass  the spring boot applicaiton

Comment: You can use Nginx as a reverse proxy to route `/home` to the Spring application and other paths to serve the React application, that's a pretty typical setup, yes.  It's a little hard to tell just from the fragment of code you've included what might be going wrong; can you edit the question to include some more details?

Comment: What's actually going wrong?  Have you tried adding a route for `/home` to that Nginx configuration?  Can you combine the two Compose files into just one, and remove some of the unnecessary options (`container_name:`, `volumes:`, `expose:`, `networks:`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added this it in nginx.conf. I edited question!

Comment: From the point of view of the Nginx container, `localhost` is the Nginx container.  The Compose service name `home` should work as a host name, and you need the process's standard port ignoring `ports:`, so `http://home:8080`, the same way you refer to `http://client:3000` for the React dev server container.

Comment: @DavidMaze what is React dev server container? http://localhost:3000/home shows 'Proxy error: Could not proxy request /home from localhost:3000 to http://home_con:2004/ (ECONNREFUSED)'.

Comment: It looks like the `home` service inside Docker is listening on port 8080; it's mapped to host port 2004 but connections between containers don't use that.